# extract, cut, process strings in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have basically 4 txt files with records such as

```
FILE 1

localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:13

localhost_access_2018-07-20.tar.gz:17

localhost_access_2018-07-21.tar.gz:12

localhost_access_2018-07-22.tar.gz:4

localhost_access_2018-07-23.tar.gz:2

localhost_access_2018-07-24.tar.gz:2905

localhost_access_2018-07-25.tar.gz:10440

localhost_access_2018-07-26.tar.gz:2644

localhost_access_2018-07-27.tar.gz:1896

localhost_access_2018-07-28.tar.gz:1238

localhost_access_2018-07-29.tar.gz:932


FILE 2

localhost_access_2018-06-19.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-20.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-21.tar.gz:1

localhost_access_2018-06-22.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-23.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-24.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-25.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-06-26.tar.gz:1

localhost_access_2018-06-27.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-07-04.tar.gz:2

localhost_access_2018-07-05.tar.gz:3

localhost_access_2018-07-06.tar.gz:6

localhost_access_2018-07-07.tar.gz:0

localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:15
```

etc.

each of the 4 files has redundant dates such in this case `localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:15` but different final numbers (after the :).

For the same dates, I have to: cut "`local_host_access_`" leaving only the date in a single new txt file (without changing it both in value and format), and I have to cut .tar.gz.

In addition I have to sum each of the values for the dates which are the same:

Hence, if there are 4 "localhost_access_2018-07-19" dates in the 4 different files, I have to sum each of the number XYZ after the value .gz:"XYZ".

Example:

```
localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:1

localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:2

localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:3

localhost_access_2018-07-19.tar.gz:4
```

should return in the single output of text, in a new file

```
2018-07-19:10
```

I've put [my attempt as an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476236/100397), but I'd appreciate better solutions (and explanations). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try also this simple `awk` approach:

```
awk -F"[_.:]" '                                 # set field separator to "_", ".", or ":"
        {SUM[$3] += $NF                         # sum all trailing fields in array indexed by the date
        }
END     {for (s in SUM) print s, SUM[s]         # print the date and the respective sum
        }
' OFS=":" file[123]                             # set output field separator; have shell expand file names 1 - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sum duplicate row values with awk ; Columns 3 and 6
awk -F '[_.:]' '{seen[$3]+=$6}END{for (i in seen) print i, seen[i]}' OFS=":" node[1-4].txt | 

sort > log.txt
```

Source for "# Sum duplicate row values with awk" 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024296/sum-duplicate-row-values-with-awk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this a useful use of `cat`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No! I've removed sed and the first sort too.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F 'localhost_access_' ' 
    {
         n=substr($2,1+index($2,":"));  
         gsub(".tar.gz.*","",$2);
         str[$2]+=n
    }
    END{
        for (i in str){
            print i":"str[i]
        }
    }' node1.txt node2.txt node3.txt node4.txt | sort -to > output.txt

    output_not_sorted=$(cat output.txt);

    # sort output by date

    exit
```

Let me know if this can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Given the two files that you show at the start of your question, and assuming that they actually don't contain blank lines:

```
$ awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' '
    { sum[$1]+=$2 }
    END { for (key in sum) {
        split(key,f,"[_.]")
        print f[3],sum[key] } }' file* | sort
2018-06-19:0
2018-06-20:0
2018-06-21:1
2018-06-22:0
2018-06-23:0
2018-06-24:0
2018-06-25:0
2018-06-26:1
2018-06-27:0
2018-07-04:2
2018-07-05:3
2018-07-06:6
2018-07-07:0
2018-07-19:28
2018-07-20:17
2018-07-21:12
2018-07-22:4
2018-07-23:2
2018-07-24:2905
2018-07-25:10440
2018-07-26:2644
2018-07-27:1896
2018-07-28:1238
2018-07-29:932
```

Use the filename as the key in an associative array called `sum` and collect the sum for each filename therein.  At the end, iterate over the keys of `sum` and print out the date part of each key together with the sum.  The date part of the key is the third field after splitting on dots and underscores.

The result is the piped though `sort`.

---

Shorter, but essentially the same as the above (but uses only the date as the key in the `sum` array):

```
awk -F '[_.:]' -v OFS=':' '
    { sum[$3]+=$6 }
    END { for (d in sum) print d, sum[d] }' file*
```